# WPF Prism modules not being initialized using App.config method

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism

I'm trying to load some modules in a test WPF project I'm using to learn Prism. I'm not getting any runtime errors and the window loads like it should, but the modules I've created are never getting initialized. I know this is the case since I added code to create a pop up window when the initialization code is run. From my understanding the code in the Bootstrapper should be creating a module catalog and initializing all of the modules. My module catalog method of choice is using an App.config file.

The relevant code is below. If anyone has ideas as to what the issue might be please share!

---

An additional piece of info that's potentially relevant is a warning I'm getting after building. The error is below, and if anyone's interested in the relevant build output information it's refering to let me know.

> Warning   15  Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1697    5   EmailClient

Here's the start of the relevant build output information:

> There was a conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes".

---

Bootstrapper

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
    }

    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
        base.InitializeModules();
    }

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
    }


    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

---

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Prism" />
  </configSections>


  <modules>
    <module assemblyFile="EmailService.dll" moduleName="EmailService" moduleType="EmailService.ModuleDefinitions.Module, EmailService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" startupLoaded="true" />
    <module assemblyFile="MailSelectionUI.dll" moduleName="MailSelectionUI" moduleType="MailSelectionUI.ModuleDefinitions.Module, MailSelectionUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" startupLoaded="true">
      <dependencies>
        <dependency moduleName="EmailService" />
      </dependencies>
    </module>
  </modules>


  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

---

Module (for MailSelectionUI)

```
public class Module : IModule
{
    public Module(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MailSelectionUI Loaded");
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("FolderSelectionRegion", typeof(MailSelectionView));
    }

    IRegionManager regionManager;
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried adding the module to ModuleCatalog in the bootstrapper instead of app.xaml and see whether the same happens?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been away from the project these past few days. Yes, it does work when I add it via code in the bootstrapper. Makes me think there's some issue with accessing or finding the App.config file, but I'm not sure how I'd test that to be sure honestly.