# What type of project should I create if I want them to act as individual modules in Prism WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm having some issues using an App.config file to load modules as outlined in [another question I started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995215/wpf-prism-modules-not-being-initialized-using-app-config-method) and was thinking through what the issue might be. I'm using [Mike Taulty's Prism tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ni5YuyYR8-Q&index=5&list=LLwJkr8C5p2x04YxVJ6I6ajQ), in which you create individual projects within the solution to act as containers for the modules.

Some of the projects are created as a Class Library, while others should be console applications. I have my main project (with the Shell, Bootstrapper, etc) as a Console Application, but I ran into an error stating "[the project] does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" when setting the sub projects as Console Applications.

My solution? Set them up as Class Libraries instead since it gets rid of the error! I think it's possible that the modules aren't loading because they're Class Libraries, but I have no idea since I'm so new to all of this. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules should be class libraries. Only the shell needs to be an executable as this is the entry point of the application. The shell executes, starts the bootstrapper which discovers the modules based on how you configure the module catalogs.

As an extension to this, if a module project is declaring a lot of WPF views and custom controls it may make sense to declare the project as a WPF Custom Control library to get the project set up nicely out of the box rather that just a plain old class library. But either way never a module is never an executable such as a WPF or Console application.